# Why redis sds expose buf part to upper layer instead of whole sdshdr

Tags: c, pointers, redis, encapsulation

When redis creates a `sds` (simple dynamic string), it inits whole `sdshdr` struct, then just returns buf part.

```
sds sdsnewlen(const void *init, size_t initlen) {

    struct sdshdr *sh;

    if (init) {
        sh = zmalloc(sizeof(struct sdshdr)+initlen+1);
    } else {
        sh = zcalloc(sizeof(struct sdshdr)+initlen+1);
    }

    if (sh == NULL) return NULL;

    sh->len = initlen;
    sh->free = 0;

    if (initlen && init)
        memcpy(sh->buf, init, initlen);
    sh->buf[initlen] = '\0';

    // just return buf part
    return (char*)sh->buf;
}
```

When redis needs to manipulate `sds`, it has to calculate the pointer to `sdshdr` struct. For exapmle, `sdsclear` function (lazy deletion of `sds`):

```
void sdsclear(sds s) {
    // calculate the pointer to sdshdr
    struct sdshdr *sh = (void*) (s-(sizeof(struct sdshdr)));

    sh->free += sh->len;
    sh->len = 0;
    sh->buf[0] = '\0';
}
```

Is that for hiding `sds` inner structure from upper layer?

Comment: So that stuff that doesn't know about SDS can still (under the right circumstances), use it as a `char *`, I would suppose... but I don't think this is the kind of question that's really answerable on SO.

Comment: @hobbs Maybe it isn't for the purpose of using it as `char*` , because `sds` implements its own version of `strlen`, `strcat`, `strcpy`, and so on. This question came to me when I read redis source code. But I couldn't figure it out myself, so I raised it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what @hobbs said - sds looks like a regular char buffer so you can use it with regular string functions (e.g. strcmp)